# Slice the string from Django template tag's variable

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is it possible to slice the string from Django template tag's variable?

Let's say **some_variable** contain "abcde"
I want it to be sliced to be "abc"

On Django's template, I tried like this.

```
{{some_variable[:-2]}}
```

It does not work.

If it's possible to slice words from Django template tag's variable, please advise me how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can work with the [**`|slice`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice):

```
{{ some_variable|slice:":-2" }}
```

This works both for lists and strings. For example:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> Template('{{ foo|slice:":-2" }}').render(Context({'foo': 'abcde'}))
'abc'
```

Using `{{ some_variable[:-2] }}` is not possible: Django's template language does not allow function calls, subscripting, operators, etc. Only a sublanguage of Python is supported, mainly to prevent people from writing business logic in the templates.